# Using neuroscience to study a new organism

Tags: neuroscience, neuroanatomy, reproducible-research

Consider a situation where you discover a new species and of organism. Using research methods of neuroscience or otherwise, how would you go about analyzing the nervous system and the brain of this organism?

I’d like to hear people’s approach to this hypothetical starting from non invasive methods like MRI, fMRI and CT scans all the way to invasive methods like neuroanatomical injections (fluorescence, radioactive tracers, etc) and physically viewing axonal connections and lengths.

Comment: StackExchange is intended for specific answerable questions; this question is more like a discussion question and is very very broad and opinion-based.

Comment: I also don't see why studying a new species would be any different from studying a known species.

Comment: perhaps another way to word this is to ask "what are the series of questions that are necessary to establish a new model system?"  it seems that while this is more of a 'discussion question', it is an interesting discussion...